# Make a dataframe from list of variables which are lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of variables in which each variable is a list. And I want to use that list to form a dataframe.

```
A=[1,2]
B=[4,3]
C=[A,B]
```

I want to create the dataframe using the list C that looks like this:

```
A B
1 4
2 3
```

I tried doing it like this

```
headers=['A','B']
df = pd.DataFrame(C, columns=headers)
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions on how to achieve it?

Comment: `C` is not a list of variables. It's a list of *values* that were bound to `A` and `B` at the time `C` was defined.

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert in python, but is there any way to directly use list C to obtain the data frame?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? If you *display* the dataframe, you get additional row indices displayed, but the expected columns exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
headers=['A','B']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers)

for i in range(len(headers)):
    df[headers[i]] = pd.Series(C[i])
```

```
#output
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  3
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a list of *columns*, but `DataFrame` expects a list of *rows*. You can transpose your list using `zip`

```
>>> A=[1,2]
>>> B=[4,3]
>>> C=[A,B]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(zip(*C), columns=headers)
>>> df
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  3
```

Or, zip `A` and `B` in the first place:

```
>>> C = zip(A, B)
>>> pd.DataFrame(C, columns=headers)
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  3
```

Comment: Actually this is a small example of what I am trying to do, in my use case there are 13 variables with 225 data each but when I do the same. I get the error "ValueError: 13 columns passed, passed data had 225 columns"

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly Good point. Maybe the OP can update their question to make this clear.

Comment: @SHIVANSHUSAHOO How is the list `C` in the real code? You should have a dictionary probably, not a list "of variables" (See @chepner first comment to the original post).

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion I have updated the example to make it clear.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly I have created the list myself, I can choose a dictionary but I wanted to find if there is a way to directly use the list.